# Cyclomatic Complexity edges

Tags: testing

So I'm trying to figure out if that blue line is in the right place, I know that I should have 9 edges but not sure if it's correct.

The code

```
public int getResult(int p1, int p2) {
int result = 0; // 1
if (p1 == 0) {  // 2
    result += 1; //3
} else {     
    result += 2; //4
}
if (p2 == 0) {   //5
    result += 3; //6
} else {
    result += 4; //7
}
    return result; //8 exit node
}
```

so 8 nodes and it should have 9 edges, right? Did I do the right thing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the blue line is placed correctly because after the 3rd line, your program is going to jump to the 5th line.
The easiest way to compute cyclomatic complexity without drawing any flow diagram is as follows:

1. Count all the loops in the program for, while, do-while, if. Assign a value of 1 to each loop. Else should not be counted here.
2. Assign a value of 1 to each switch case. Default case should not be counted here.
3. Cyclomatic complexity = Total number of loops + 1
   In your program, there are 2 if loops, so the cyclomatic complexity would be 3(2+1)

You can cross-check it with the standard formulae available as well which are as below:
C = E-N+2 (9-8+2=3)

OR

C = Number of closed regions + 1 (2+1=3)

Comment: Just needed to know if the blue line was placed correctly, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity):

M = E − N + 2P,
where

E = the number of edges of the graph.
N = the number of nodes of the graph.
P = the number of connected components.

so:

`9 - 8 + 2*1 = 3`